# Dynamically scaling html content overflows out of screen

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a JS function that calculates the content of the html page then scales the content so that it'll fit within the screen. problem is sometimes the content will overflow out the top of the page and i cant seem to figure out a way to fix it. due to restrictions i can only use vanilla js.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8qd3bg9/3/)

```js
let scale = 0.70; //70% of screen's size
function scaleMe() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    let x = this.document.body.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    x.style.transform = '';
    let width = x.firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let height = x.firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    if ((screen.availHeight || screen.height - 30) <= window.innerHeight)
      scale = (height >= width) ? 1 : .85;
    else
      scale = (height > 818) ? 0.6 : scale;

    let theScale = (height > width) ? (((scale * this.innerHeight) - height) / height) : (((scale * this.innerWidth) - width) / width) + 1;
    theScale = (theScale > 1) ? 1 : theScale; //limit the scale to 100% of its original size.

    if (height > width && height > this.innerHeight && theScale < 0.3 && (screen.availHeight || screen.height - 30) <= window.innerHeight)
      theScale = 0.7;

    /*Added to deal with wonky Title Pages in fullscreen*/
    if ((screen.availHeight || screen.height - 30) <= window.innerHeight) {
      try {
        if (height > this.innerHeight)
          theScale = 0.75; //height is greater than window height.
        if (x.firstElementChild.src.includes("TitlePage") || x.firstElementChild.src.includes("TitleCover.png"))
          theScale = 1.35; //images too small
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("no img source on pg"); //ignore.
      }
    }

    theScale = Math.abs(theScale); //prevent negative scale that flips img.
    x.style.transform = 'scale(' + theScale + ')';
  }, 60);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0pt;
  margin-bottom: 0pt;
  margin-left: 0pt;
  margin-right: 0pt;
  text-indent: 20pt;
  width: max-content;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 1.125em;
}

.title {
  font-size: 30pt;
  margin-bottom: 10pt;
  text-indent: 0em;
}

.list1 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 18pt;
  margin-top: 4pt;
  text-indent: -14pt;
}

.list2 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 6pt;
  margin-left: 40pt;
  text-indent: 0pt;
}

.bullets {
  float: left;
  color: red;
}

.list-item {
  margin-left: 0.9em;
  text-indent: initial;
}

.img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>some title</title>
</head>

<body onload="scaleMe();" onresize="scaleMe();">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <p class="title">Title</p>
      <div class="list1"><span class="bullets">&#x2022;</span>
        <div class="list-item">content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"><span class="bullets">-</span>
        <div class="list-item">list option 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"><span class="bullets">-</span>
        <div class="list-item">list option 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"><span class="bullets">-</span>
        <div class="list-item">list option 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list1"><span class="bullets">&#x2022;</span>
        <div class="list-item">content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"><span class="bullets">-</span>
        <div class="list-item">list option 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list2"><span class="bullets">-</span>
        <div class="list-item">list option 1</div>
      </div>
      <p class="img">
        <image src="" height="721" width="1179"></image>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to figure out the "sometimes" - like, "hey, when `theScale` is `> 1` it overflows"

Comment: @James that's the thing. it overflows sometimes when theScale is 0.7 , the content of the page isnt known to me it can be any size. sometimes the content needs to be scaled down to fit in screen. sometimes it needs to scale up so its big enough for the screen page